# Select sql from database only from yesterday

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I select my sql database only from yesterday? Here is my code:

```
      SELECT *, COUNT(visitors.usr_id) as usr_count FROM user, visitors WHERE visitors.usr_id = $usr_id GROUP BY $usr_id ORDER BY usr_count LIMIT 1
```

My database name is timein and the way it inputs the date and time that the INSERT was done. Here is the code:

```
      Database column :    timein

      Database insert looks like :    2012-9-6 9:11:35
```

Basically I want to be able to SELECT and COUNT only from yesterday. How can I SELECT COUNT from my sql database from yesterday only?

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag because the syntax is MySQL.

Comment: Seeing strings like `$usr_id` in your query is extremely worrying. Are you sure you've [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) those values to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one  add a condition for yesterday like `timein <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ,  timein >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY;`

```
SELECT *, COUNT(visitors.usr_id) as usr_count 
FROM user, visitors 
WHERE visitors.usr_id = $usr_id
AND timein <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND timein >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
GROUP BY $usr_id 
ORDER BY usr_count
LIMIT 1
```

Or you can use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT *, COUNT(visitors.usr_id) as usr_count 
FROM user, visitors 
WHERE visitors.usr_id = $usr_id
AND timein BETWEEN  NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND  NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY;
GROUP BY $usr_id 
ORDER BY usr_count
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not make sense.  You are doing a cross join between `user` and `visitors` and then filtering only on visitors.  I suspect you want something like:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(visitors.usr_id) as usr_count
FROM user join
     visitors
     on visitors.usr_id = user.usr_id
WHERE user.usr_id = $usr_id
GROUP BY $usr_id
ORDER BY usr_count
LIMIT 1;
```

The `where` clause to get yesterday's data would be:

```
WHERE date(timein) = date(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Or, if you have an index on `timein`:

```
WHERE timein >= date(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) and timein < date(NOW())
```